# What is Debugging in android

Tags: android

what is debugging in android and what is the benefits of debugging android apps?

i have tried to Search in google but did't found any thing

```
ss ss ss s s s ss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio includes a debugger that enables you to debug apps running on the Android Emulator or a connected Android device. With the Android Studio debugger, you can do the following:

- Select a device to debug your app on.
- Set breakpoints in your Java and C/C++ code.
- Examine variables and evaluate expressions at runtime.
- Capture screenshots and videos of your app.
  Please briefly read  [Debugging Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)

Comment: explain more please

Comment: Have you read the link I posted?